# sum of a field giving incorrect values when queried

Tags: soql, custom-field

I have a field called purchase price in orders table. When I query for those orders, I got 4 records. They are as follows

[image]

Here, as per the above query, when i sum purchase_price__c, i am getting 194.99. 
But, when I update the query to return the sum(purchase_price__c), I am getting the result as 216.

[image]

Is this issue due to sum function or if we sum the field, will it consider deleted records as well? I'm  pretty confused here. Why do the numbers differ?

Comment: what does ```count(purchase_price__c)``` return?

Comment: Do you have multi-currency enabled?

Comment: No @AdrianLarson. We do not have multi currency enabled

Comment: Count(Purchase_Price__c) is returning 4 records @kurunve

Comment: You could check the deleted records hypothesis. Do you have any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Notice the `Deleted and archived records: Include` in top right?**

**LIST:**

[image]

**SUM:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Salesforce-sas. That was set to exclude when I was querying and that means it didnt include deleted records...I'm wondering why the sum is more when when compared to individual records. Please suggest

Comment: :). pls mark solved if solved

Comment: I wish it would but it didnt @Salesforcesas. I'm getting the same no.of records with deleted records included and excluded.

Comment: can u verify in salesforce developer console?

Comment: I did @Salesforcesas. I am getting the same total as workbench.